# Index out of bounds, Java bukkit plugin

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, bukkit

I'm getting index out of bounds errors in my Bukkit plugin, and it's really beginning to piss me off...

I for the life of me can't figure this issue out!

Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

This is where I believe the code to be erroring...

```
for(int i = 0; i <= staffOnline.size(); i++) {
            if(i == staffOnline.size()) {
                staffList = staffList + staffOnline.get(i);
            } else {
                staffList = staffList + staffOnline.get(i) + ", ";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objects in collections in Java are usually indexed starting with zero. Also, the method `.size()` returns the numbers of elements inside the collection.

So, if the size is 1, you can only access the element 0. Not 0 and 1 like you're doing, because the element 1 do not exist.

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < staffOnline.size(); i++) { // changed here
        if(i == staffOnline.size() - 1) { // and here :)
            staffList = staffList + staffOnline.get(i);
        } else {
            staffList = staffList + staffOnline.get(i) + ", ";
        }
    }
```